# How to add second sidemenu from other side

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

How can I add a second `sidemenu`? I have the normal `sidemenu` on the left side which works great. Now I want to add a second `sidemenu` with filter options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you can read in [MenuToggle from Ionic2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuToggle/) you can do it by first creating two `ion-menu` in your `app.html` (or where you want to define the second menu)

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="left" id="menu1">

  <ion-toolbar secondary>
    <ion-title>Menu 1</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item menuClose="menu1" detail-none>
        Close Menu 1
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" id="menu2">

  <ion-toolbar danger>
    <ion-title>Menu 2</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item menuClose="menu2" detail-none>
        Close Menu 2
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

Please notice the `side="left"` and `side="right"` attributes in the `ion-menu` element. We'll use that later to know which menu should be opened (the `id` attribute could be also used in the same way).

Then, in your page, add to each `menuToggle` which menu should be opened by assigning to it the `side` attribute we defined earlier (or the `id` if you prefer to do so).

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <button menuToggle="left" start>
      <ion-icon name="menu">L</ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button menuToggle="right" end>
      <ion-icon name="menu">R</ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      Multiple Menus in Ionic2
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

You can find a [working plnuker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/evY7Ql?p=preview).

---

**UPDATE:**

> For testing I simply moved the main  from the app.html to a
>   page's html file map.html. I didn't change the sides or ids. But the
>   menu is not appearing when clicking the button (also have been not
>   changed)

I've done that in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sdR3NB). Now, the `HomePage` has the menu on the right defined there in that hmtl file.

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" id="menu2">
  <ion-toolbar danger>
    <ion-title>Menu 2</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item menuClose="menu2" detail-none>
        Close Menu 2
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <button menuToggle="left" start>
      <ion-icon name="menu">L</ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button menuToggle="right" end>
      <ion-icon name="menu">R</ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      Multiple Menus in Ionic2
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content #content padding>

</ion-content>
```

Please notice the `content` variable in the `<ion-content>` element. Like you can read in [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/#usage):

> To add a menu to an application, the  element should be
>   added as a sibling to the content it belongs to. A local variable
>   should be added to the content element and passed to the menu element
>   in the content property. This tells the menu which content it is
>   attached to, so it knows which element to watch for gestures.

Comment: If I put the <ion-menu> in my app.html everything is fine. But I want to define the menu in my page. Is this also possible? I have several pages which need different right menus.

Comment: Yes, that's also possible, the `ion-menu` could be in the page that is going to show it.

Comment: For testing I simply moved the main <ion-menu> from the app.html to a page's html file map.html. I didn't change the sides or ids. But the menu is not appearing when clicking the button (also have been not changed).

Comment: Thank you very very much Seba! The missing #content in the <ion-content> was the problem. There is still a little problem: The left menu (my normal regular menu) pushes the content and the <ion-header> to the right when opening. I duplicated this <ion-menu> and changed the side. So its the same "menu". But now: If I click the button, the menu (from right) pushes the content to the left but the <ion-header> doesn't move. I don't see any differences between the left and the right menu. Thank you ;-)

Comment: If I move the second ion-menu to the app.html it works. So the problem probably is the position in the HTML structure. Hm....