# Ionic2: How to use an different ion-menu in each child view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to learn the use of the Ionic2 side menus and wish to see if I can have a separate side menu in each child view.

I have installed one of the getting started apps, which has a ion-menu in the main application, ie in the bootstrap `app.html` file we have

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">

 <ion-toolbar>
   <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>

 <ion-content>
   <ion-list>
     <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
       {{p.title}}
     </button>
   </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

I have then added my own page, and in the initial root page `getting-started.ts` of the sample app I add the the following to navigate to my new page..

```
public goToSideMenuPage(): void{    
   this._navController.push(SideMenuPage);
```

I also add a button to call the above handler.

In the SideMenuPage, I would like it to have it's own completely different side menu. I have tried the following...

```
<ion-menu [content]="thecontent">
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-title>Menu title</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>

<ion-content>
 <ion-list>
    <button>button1</button>
    <button>button2</button>
 </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-content #thecontent>
  <div>Main contents text</div>
 </ion-content>
```

However, when I goto my page, all I see is `Main contents text` in the upper left corner. I don't see the menu hamburger icon, and if I drag to the right, I see the app main menu as set in `app.html`, and not my own "local" menu with contents of

```
<button>button1</button>
<button>button2</button>
```

In doco found [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/), the demo does show the side menu being swapped at runtime, but I cannot see the actual code for it anywhere. This is close to what I want to do (though I want it to swap when depending on what child page I navigate to), so it does look like it might be possible to do, but I just don't quite see how I should be doing it.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information you're looking for is in the [MenuController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuController/) section from Ionic2 docs. That could be done by adding the menus in the `app.html` but assigning them an id like this:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="left" id="menu1">
  <ion-toolbar secondary>
    <ion-title>Menu 1</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item menuClose="menu1" detail-none>
        Close Menu 1
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" id="menu2">
  <ion-toolbar danger>
    <ion-title>Menu 2</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item menuClose="menu2" detail-none>
        Close Menu 2
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
```

And then, in each page we can decide which menu should be activated like this:

```
  constructor(private menu: MenuController, private nav: NavController) { }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    // Use the id to enable/disable the menus
    this.menu.enable(true, 'menu1');
    this.menu.enable(false, 'menu2');
  }
```

Also, please notice that I show the second page by using `this.nav.setRoot(Page1);` instead of using something like `this.nav.push(Page1);`.

---

EDIT: If you want both menus active at the same time, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557621/how-to-add-second-sidemenu-from-other-side/38563222#38563222).

---

EDIT 2: Just like @peterc say in the comments:

> I found this also worked if I had my side menu in my page
>   sidemenu-page.html and set this.menu.enable(true, 'menu1'); in it's
>   component (**so there is the option to have the side menu with the
>   markup of the page that will switch to it**).

I add that to the answer because the view where it's going to be used seems to be a better place to put the menus instead of the `app.html`.

Comment: thankyou very much! This is what I was after. The two keys here were using the setRoot, and also using the MenuController.enable. I found this also worked if I had my side menu in my page sidemenu-page.html and set `this.menu.enable(true, 'menu1');` in it's component (so there is the option to have the side menu with the markup of the page that will switch to it.

Comment: Glad I could help :) If it's ok for you, I'll add your comment to the answer so other users can find that information easily...

Comment: Yes for sure add anything in there so it's all in one place for others..

Comment: @peterc Could you provide an example, because I get this error: `Property 'content' does not exist on type 'MyPage'`

Comment: @user623396 I'll put the code I had at the time in an answer below (so I can format it a bit). This was for an older beta Ionic version, but hopefully still correct (or at least close). The sample project I was using broke some time back, and I abandoned it

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this as part of info given by @sebaferreras for the sake of @user623396

To have the side menu in the actual view, I had the following...

```
    <ion-menu [content]="thecontent" id='menu1'>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>

      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <button>button1</button>
          <button>button2</button>      
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>

    <ion-navbar *navbar>
      <button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <ion-title>Getting Started</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

    <ion-content #thecontent>
      <div>Some text</div>  
    </ion-content>
```

And then in the component file

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {MenuController, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

    // Use the pipe TranslatePipe to use in the markup
    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/sidemenu-page/sidemenu-page.html'
    })
    export class SideMenuPage {
      public rootPage = SideMenuPage;

      public myVal: string;  

      constructor(private menu: MenuController, private nav: NavController, private tranlate: TranslateService){
      }

      ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.menu.enable(true, 'menu1');
      }  
    }
```

Hopefully this is still correct for the latest version of Ionic (it's been a while since I have looked at this example)