# Two Ionic2 menus: One is shown. The other is not

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my Ionic2 app I have two pages that each have very similar menus each. Those menus are named. However one page does show its menu and the other does not. The respective menu HTML code is inside the respective XXX.html. Is there something preventing Ionic2 from having two menus on the same side for different pages?

story.html works:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar #storyNav>
    <ion-title>Originaltöne</ion-title>
    <button ion-button menuToggle="checkMenu" right>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <!-- <ion-item (click)="putOnWatchlist(entry)" *ngFor="let entry of dataToShow">
    {{ entry.textbody }}
  </ion-item> -->
</ion-content>

<ion-menu id="checkMenu" side="right" [content]="storyNav">
  <ion-content>
    Lorem ipsum...
    <ion-item menuClose="checkMenu" detail-none>Close Menu</ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

But story-dashboard.html does not:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar #dashboardNav>
    <ion-title>Originaltöne</ion-title>
    <button ion-button menuToggle="favMenu" right>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-item >
    Lorem ipsum...
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>

<ion-menu id="favMenu" side="right" [content]="dashboardNav">
  <ion-content>
    Lorem ipsum...
    <ion-item menuClose="favMenu" detail-none>Close Menu</ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

Comment: you sure placing exactly the same `script` and `links` to your css and js files in the `story-dashboard.html`?

Comment: Yes, it was the same script. The problem was, that I really can't have two menus on the same side without disabling one with a MenuController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple error, when you create a page automatically he will be displaying the `app.html` (is located in `myapp/src/app/`), so with that information when we work with menus, we use then inside the `app.html` and not inside the single page.

So.. You can create two differents menus inside the `app.html`, and call the one you want to open, you should using buttons with menuToggle likely `<button ion-button menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button>`, or to call a specify one call a function with the click.

```
 // id of the menu you want call
 openMenu(id) {
   this.menuCtrl.open(id);
 }
```

For more information, I recommend you seeing the docs about [Menu](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/) and [MenuController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuController/)

Comment: This approach led me to the right solution. After searching the right way I also found the solution here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569461/ionic2-how-to-use-an-different-ion-menu-in-each-child-view?rq=1

I needed to specifically enable and disable the respective menus using a MenuController.